# Is only AWS ELB supporting supporting http/2 sufficient in stack

Tags: http, amazon-web-services

If we have AWS ELB terminating SSL and Apache 2.2 with mod_proxy talking to tomcat 7.x.
Apache and tomcat do not support HTTP/2.

Will we get any performance gains if only AWS ELB starts supporting HTTP/2?

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, the ELB does not natively support http2. You can enable support by handling SSL termination on your instances and using tcp passthrough for all connections.

In order to do this, you will need to change from apache to nginx as apache does not officially support it yet.

Comment: So whenever ELB starts supporting HTTP/2, can we continue to use non HTTP/2 compliant versions of Apache and Tomcat?

Comment: I presume so. But i don't think you will see as much performance benefit doing that. AWS hasn't said anything other than they are looking at supporting it. I would start looking at upgrading if its possible. In some cases http2 can be a significant performance improvement.